# What is the difference between printf() and puts() in C?

Tags: c, string, output, printf, puts

I know you can print with `printf()` and `puts()`. I can also see that `printf()` allows you to interpolate variables and do formatting.

Is `puts()` merely a primitive version of `printf()`. Should it be used for every possible `printf()` without string interpolation?

Comment: [**puts() vs printf() - C/C++ Answers**](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/527094-puts-vs-printf)

Comment: Just a note on using printf instead of puts: never, ever do a `printf(variable)` to print a string. Use `puts(variable)` or `printf("%s', variable)`. There's a security risk in using a variable format string: if the variable can be written by an attacker they can attack the program by using format strings.

Comment: @ZanLynx: Is that the correct quoting around `%s`?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

`puts` is simpler than `printf` but be aware that the former automatically appends a newline.  If that's not what you want, you can `fputs` your string to stdout or use `printf`.

Comment: I think it's also important to mention the additional arguments printf take for adding additional variables into the outputted string.

Answer (score 129):

(This is pointed out in a comment by Zan Lynx, but I think it deserves an answer - given that the accepted answer doesn't mention it).

The essential difference between `puts(mystr);` and `printf(mystr);` is that in the latter the argument is interpreted as a **formatting string**. The result will be often the same (except for the added newline) if the string doesn't contain any control characters (`%`) but if you cannot rely on that (if `mystr` is a variable instead of a literal), you should  *not* use it.

So, it's generally dangerous - and conceptually **wrong** - to pass a dynamic string as single argument of `printf`:

```c
char * myMessage;
// ... myMessage gets assigned at runtime, unpredictable content
printf(myMessage);  // <--- WRONG! (what if myMessage contains a '%' char?)
puts(myMessage);    // ok 
printf("%s\n",myMessage); // ok, equivalent to the previous, perhaps less efficient
```

The same applies to `fputs` vs `fprintf` (but `fputs` doesn't add the newline).

Comment: In what way would using `printf()` be less efficient? At run time? At compile time?

Comment: @franklin at runtime, because `printf` needs to parse the format string. However, this should normally be irrelevant. Further, a clever compiler could optimize this, and replace the `printf` with call to `puts`

Answer (score 41):

Besides formatting, `puts` returns a nonnegative integer if successful or `EOF` if unsuccessful; while `printf` returns the number of characters printed (not including the trailing null).

Comment: When I've tested this, puts returns the number of characters in the string including the terminating character, whereas printf returns the number of characters printed without the terminating character. Which is technically consistent with your definition, as the former is a non-negative integer, but I'm not sure whether that's what you meant to say.

Comment: @lou, are you sure the extra including come from the null terminator but not the '\n'?

Answer (score 21):

In simple cases, the compiler converts calls to `printf()` to calls to `puts()`.

For example, the following code will be compiled to the assembly code I show next.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    printf("Hello world!");
    return 0;
}
```

```
push rbp
mov rbp,rsp
mov edi,str.Helloworld!
call dword imp.puts
mov eax,0x0
pop rbp
ret
```

In this example, I used GCC version 4.7.2 and compiled the source with `gcc -o hello hello.c`.

Comment: And what about new line that puts places in stdout?

Comment: It should have been ``printf("Hello world!\n");`` gcc indeed translates that to puts. Since it's an old message, I will edit it myself.

Comment: How did you read the assembly code after compiling the C code?

Comment: @KorayTugay : the `-save-temps` option for gcc does that

Comment: You could also use a tool like gdb to disassemble a binary.

Comment: Also $ objdump -d printf.exe -M intel

Comment: By the way in gcc 7.5.0 assembly looks like = call printf@PLT

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, `printf()` hauls in more code than `puts()` regardless of the format string.

If I don't need the formatting, I don't use `printf`.  However, `fwrite` to `stdout` works a lot faster than `puts`.

```
static const char my_text[] = "Using fwrite.\n";
fwrite(my_text, 1, sizeof(my_text) - sizeof('\0'), stdout);
```

*Note: per comments, '\0' is an integer constant.  The correct expression should be `sizeof(char)` as indicated by the comments.*

Comment: "fwrite to stdout works a lot faster than puts." - What could possibly be the reason?

Comment: @AntonyHatchkins It's typically not "a lot" faster. puts(), however, does have to perform an strlen() call every time on your string whereas if the size is known with fwrite() it can be avoided. That's pretty much the only real contributer to a performance difference.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. `'\0'` has type `int`, so on most systems this will print `Using fwrit`. If you want to print 1 less byte, just use 1. `sizeof (char)`, which is likely what you intended here, is guaranteed to be 1.

Answer (score 11):

```
int puts(const char *s);
```

**puts()** writes the string s and a trailing newline to stdout.

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

The function **printf()** writes output to stdout, under the control of a format string that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output.

I'll use this opportunity to ask you to read the documentation.

Answer (score 10):

Right, `printf` could be thought of as a more powerful version of `puts`. `printf` provides the ability to *format* variables for output using format specifiers such as `%s`, `%d`, `%lf`, etc...

Answer (score 8):

the printf() function is used to print both strings and variables to the screen  while the puts() function only permits you to print a string only to your screen.

Answer (score 2):

`puts` is the simple choice and adds a new line in the end and `printf`writes the output from a formatted string.

See the documentation for [`puts`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/puts) 
and for [`printf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

I would recommend to use only `printf` as this is more consistent than switching method, i.e if you are debbugging it is less painfull to search all printfs than `puts` and `printf`. Most times you want to output a variable in your printouts as well, so `puts` is mostly used in example code.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing `puts()` and `printf()`, even though their memory consumption is almost the same, `puts()` takes more time compared to `printf()`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - do you have reliable sources for that claim? Or some reasons to explain this difference?

Comment: I do not believe that puts() takes more time than printf(). Note that puts automatically appends a newline.