# Basic arithmatic code is not being executed in Vs Code

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code

I just started with programming, so please bear with me. I tried running a simple addition code in C language in Vs Code. It fails to run and no error is displayed. Below is the screenshot of what I see every time I try to run the code

[image]

Here is the code I wrote.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   int length, breadth;
   printf("What is the length of the rectangle\n");
   scanf("%d" , &length);

   printf("What is the breadth of the rectangle\n");
   scanf("%d", &breadth);

   printf("The area of your rectangle is %d", length*breadth);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19458884/why-is-this-trivial-c-program-detected-as-a-virus ... maybe your anti-virus raises a false positive

Comment: By convention, success is reported by an exit code of 0. Likewise, by convention, an exit code not equal to 0 represents failure.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably an issue with how you configured VSCode to run `C` programs; Try to compile & run the executable separately.

Comment: There's a comment, not an answer.