# C preprocessor: macro function to call printf()

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to conditionally use either printf() or a statement:

```
#define USE_PRINTF

#ifdef USE_PRINTF
#define macrofn(str) printf(str)
#else
#define macrofn(str) some_statement
#ifndef USE_PRINTF
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Please post the code which is calling on the macro.

Comment: Not adding `#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: This is not correct... You should have been using an `#endif` instead of the `#ifndef USE_PRINTF` which means *"if USE_PRINTF is not defined"*, which already is being handled by the `#else` part. You absolutely need an `#endif` for each `#if`.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Nice catch!! But won't compiler complain as no matching `endif` for this error.

Comment: Thank you all - typo galore - it's clearly too early in the morning

Comment: What's the purpose of using `printf` with just one argument? Shouldn't `puts` be more suitable in most such cases? See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16813480/908515

Comment: @undur_gongor `puts` prints an additional new line when it reaches the end of the string pushed into. So they aren't truly analogous even for the cases where `printf` has only one argument. Maybe `#define macrofn(str) for ( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ ) putchar( str[i] );`

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: I'm aware about that. But even if you want to avoid the line break, you should rather define the macro as `printf("%s", str)`.

Comment: @undur_gongor How about `#define macrofn( str, ... ) printf( str, __VA_ARGS__ )` then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to include the `<stdio.h>` before the macro definition. What you really need is `#endif` for the `#if` you have started. For example, the following programme will work all fine:

```
#define USE

#ifdef USE
#define asd printf("asd")
#else
#define asd puts("kek")
#endif

#include<stdio.h>

int main( ) {
    asd;
    getchar( );
    return 0;
}
```

So... yeah.

Comment: True, but it is common sense to have the includes on top. And you need it before the invocation of the macro.

Comment: @undur_gongor I also wouldn't put things in this order, but I wouldn't mind a bit if someone did, that's what being flexible is.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `#include <stdio.h>` to your file.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977233/warning-incompatible-implicit-declaration-of-built-in-function-xyz) for more information about this error message.

Comment: This is wrong, if it means what it looks like it means. One does have to `#include <stdio.h>`, but not necessarily before the macro definition.

Comment: Force of a habit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `stdio.h` if you want to use `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use this syntax:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define USE_PRINTF

#ifdef USE_PRINTF
#define macrofn(str) printf(str)
#else
#define macrofn(str) some_statement
#endif
```