# Why use printf("mystring\n") instead of just puts("mystring")?

Tags: c, printf, output, stdio, puts

I've seen this in code where just a normal string without any formatting is displayed using printf (e.g. printf("Hello World!\n").
Why not just use puts("Hello World") instead?

Comment: Because maybe next you'll want to write `printf("Hello, %s\n", name)`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2454474/what-is-the-difference-between-printf-and-puts-in-c

Comment: Because people don’t know about `puts`.

Comment: The `puts()` variant use one byte fewer memory.

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/527094-puts-vs-printf

Comment: Compilers optimize this for you anyway, and having the `\n` explicit instead of implicit is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 2):

`puts` or `fputs` should be used whenever no variables must be formatted/printed. The following would give a problem:

```
 printf("How many %s is the interest?\n");
```

Especially when the string to print is passed as a variable, it can be hard to find the error.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you want to print something that has "%" it's recommended to use `puts`

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is generally the preferred alternative, simply because it's more powerful and gives a programmer more control over their output.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to update your code later down the road, you might be using variables. `puts()` doesn't format variables, but `printf()` does. Also, `puts()` always adds the new line, so if you ever don't want a newline, then you'll want to switch to `printf()`. Basically, `printf()` allows you to maintain the code longer.

Comment: It’s not that hard to change `puts` to `printf`.

Comment: When you're maintaining thousands of lines of legacy code and multiple files, it becomes more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

> Why use `printf("mystring\n")` instead of just `puts("mystring")`?

Note: there are reasons *not* to use `printf()` like the apperance of the `'%'` character, but OP seems to want reasons *for* `printf(line_of_text)`.

Example 1: in an embedded application (code space limited) that already uses `printf()`, `puts()` may cost additional program space.

Example 2: The output of `puts()` appends a `'\n'`. This behavior catches programmers who forget this and use `puts("mystring\n")`.  Using `printf("mystring\n")` is explicit.  Using `fputs("mystring\n", stdout)` is even better.